# Iterating through a List<> and .Contains isn't catching string

Tags: c#, string, contains

I'm reading stream of text and I put the text into a List<> Collection. As I am going through the list I am trying to do this...

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();

dt1.Columns.Add("A");
dt1.Columns.Add("B");
dt1.Columns.Add("C");
dt1.Columns.Add("D");
dt1.Columns.Add("E");
dt1.Columns.Add("F");

foreach (var x in myList)
{
    if (x.Contains("<a class= "))
    {
        //Gotta get the values on the new lines
        //into an array

        dr["A"] = x;
        dt1.Rows.Add(x);
    }
}
```

The problem is...

```
if (x.Contains("<a class= "))
```

It always passes over the if statement and I have stepped through it and that string does exist. The reason for looking for that piece of string is because its the only way for me to know that values on each line after that until the next time is part of that record.

**EDIT**

The string is

```
..<a class="doctor" href="/public-register/doctor-details.aspx?view=1&id=%2082358">Aal Ali, Saleh Saif Salem A S Fares </a>(#82358)
```

Comment: are you sure the case matches ? What are the values in `myList` ?

Comment: There's also a whitespace after the `class=` which looks strange.

Comment: Based on this code, it's obvious that `myList` does not contain a string that contains the string you are searching for.  But we don't have a definition of `myList` so we can't troubleshoot any farther.

Comment: BTW: trying to parse an html with simple string ops is strange..

Comment: Also, "<a class= " has a ring of HTML to it, and, in my experience, it's unusual to put a space after an equals sign in an attribute.

Comment: The datatable code seems to be irrelevant to your problem. Your problem can be reduced to `List<string> myList = GetMyListFromSomewhere(); bool result = myList.Any(x => x.Contains("<a class= ");`. This is fairly straightforward to debug.

Comment: `<a class="doctor"...` does not contain `<a class= `. Note the space in the latter.

Comment: @Dirk, its only a piece of the string that I want because all the link info will be different

Comment: @Asad, I know that see my comment to Dirk above

Comment: @Asad, ohh ok, I read your comment wrong, sorry

Comment: @Chris If the string `x` doesn't contain `"<a class= "`, and you know this, why do you expect `x.Contains("<a class= ")` to return true?

Comment: @Asad, I just removed that whitespace. Its catching it now. I see what you are saying. If you want to put that up as the answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't see what all the down votes are for, I am pretty sure at some point in time someone will have this issue and not even realize that the cause would be a whitespace. I'm embarrassed that I glossed over that part.

Comment: @Chris In stackoverflow, you sometimes suffer from serial downvotes. As soon as a question gets downvotes sometimes some people go have a look at it to see if they agree and then they pile on to get rid of the low quality question. In your case I think the primary issue was faulty grammar, which made it difficult to understand what you are asking. Personally I prefer helping the people who ask questions to closing unclear questions.

Answer (score 2):

Its the white space after `class=`. Try this:

```
    private static void ContainsTest()
    {
        string input = "<a class=";
        string test = "<a class=\"doctor\" href=\"/public-register/doctor-details.aspx?view=1&id=%2082358\">Aal Ali, Saleh Saif Salem A S Fares </a>(#82358)";
        Console.WriteLine("test Contains input: "+test.Contains(input).ToString());
    }
```